# What uses prawn for rendering pdfs?

Tags: ruby, pdf, prawn

Just curious, how [prawn](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn) renders pdf? Does it uses a library, webkit or latex or what?

Comment: The source is right there for you to look at.

Comment: The answer is in the first sentence in the README on the Github page you linked to: "Prawn is a pure Ruby PDF generation"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure Ruby.

[This](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/prawn-ruby) might be a better place to ask a question like this.